# JavaScript count all elements on a webpage

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to count everything on a site that contains a certain string, even if it's not displayed on the page.

**I found this:**

```
window.occurrencesFunc()
```

I am not sure how to use it. I did play around with it, but nothing seemed to work.

**This is what I tried:**

```
function main() {
    function(r) {
        var amount = window.occurrencesFunc(r, "string", false);
        $('ul.reset').append('Count: ' + amount);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Where exactly did you find `window.occurrencesFunc()`? Google knows nothing about it.

Comment: not sure where you _found_ that - are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Could you be more specific. What is the string and how is it being used on the page. Depending on how its being used you might be able to get what you want with a jQuery selector.

Comment: "contains a certain string" as in, inside a tag `<tag>here</tag>` or as a class or id attribute? What do you mean by "contains".

Comment: The code you posted appears to be jQuery. If so, please add the tag to your question.

Comment: can you try this to check from console what it gives you `$('*:contains(string)').length`

Comment: The function is never called, so it's not going to do much…

Comment: @joyBlanks is a good soluction

Comment: I saw someone code where they got information from another page on the site without the script being connected to that page. They used: window.occurencesFunc(function, "anything they want to find, if it's text or a tag", false);

Comment: @Density `window.occurencesFunc` not exists on chrome for example, there is not a good option in my concept

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "count everything"? Do you want to count elements? Should it include attributes or only content? Do you want to include only things in the `body` or also in `head` (such as `meta` tags)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd get the entire page as a string:

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

And, then I'd use the match method to match for the string occurrences in the string and count them:

// the g in the regular expression says to search for a word (not part of a word)

```
var resultArray= markup.match(/WORRDDD/g);

var count = resultArray.length
```

Shorthand, would be

```
var count = (markup.match(/WORRDDD/g) || []).length;
```

Comment: I want to get the entire site as a string, not just the page

Comment: You'll need to get each page separately and do the count for each, unless you want to use something more than simple javascript.

Comment: I saw something someone wrote with javascript to count occurrences from another page

Answer (score 0):

How about a function like this?

```
function findOccurrences (string)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName ('*');
    var foundCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0, il = elements.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (!elements[i].textContent || !elements[i].textContent.match (string)) {
            continue;
        }

        foundCount++;
    }

    return 'Count: ' + foundCount;
}
```

Use it like this, HTML...

```
<div id="occurrenceCount"></div>
```

And the JavaScript...

```
var countElement = document.getElementById ('occurrenceCount');
    countElement.textContent = findOccurrences ('your string');
```

This will make the `<div>` above contain something like:

```
Count: 35
```

Comment: What exactly does this do? I tried it out. I was expecting a value of about: 6496 but instead got 41

Comment: It counts the occurrences of the given string inside every tag on the page. It should basically give you the same number that your browser does when you Ctrl+F search for something on the page. Except it counts tags that might not be visible on the page as well.

Comment: Is there a way to count all occurrences from a different page, or all pages containing a certain string in it's url?. Like: google.com which would search the whole of google?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably walk through element nodes present in the DOM

```
function countElementsMatching(needle, elements) {

    return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements)
        .map(function (node) {
            return node.textContent;
        })
        .filter(function (str) {
            return str.indexOf(needle) !== -1;
        }).length;
}
```

Usage:

```
var total = countElementsMatching('some string', document.querySelectorAll('*'));
```